# .resyslogd process is using 200% cpu

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, syslogd

First of all, a disclamer, I am not a sys admin, I was just asked to check why a VM of ours is using a lot of the cpu.
It turns out that this process is running for ever on 200%
`$top`

> PID   USER       PR NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+
>   COMMAND
>   11058 www-data  20   0  269564   5812    384 S  185.5     0.1  2:42.95   .resyslogd

After some research I figured out that this is a logger (actually I found that the logger is the rsyslog but i gess r**e**syslog is the same thing.
So i noticed that there are alot of connection attempts (from bots I am guessing) that was triggering the logger to write. So I decided to stop allowing passwords for loging in and switched to key authentication.
That did nothing for the cpu usage, even though the records on the logger where now less than before. for the random IPs that i was seeing on the logger, I added them on /etc/hosts.deny.
After all these the cpu usage has not droped at all. the same process is using more than 100% of the cpu core.
I know that the www-data is a web server, assuming apache, and dont know if it actually used for any reason.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `.resyslogd` is almost certainly a malware infection with a thin layer of "obfuscation" for the most casual of looks.

Comment: @Sven that was my first thought, but googling the name only comes up the logger, rsyslog, so I figured that this was it, since no one else seems to have the same problem. Will look at the post you mention as duplicated. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks very fishy. `rsyslogd` should definitely not be running as user `www-data`!

`.resyslogd` is definitely **NOT** the same thing as `rsyslogd`, but it's trying to pretend it's a logger process to avoid suspicions.

This is definitely not a logger. It's probably a coin miner or something similar, that has wormed its way into your server by using a weakness in your web server, or one of the scripts (CGIs, PHP, Perl, whatever) the web server is configured to run.

If you have root access (or can switch to `www-data` user), you could stop and analyze this worm. If not, you should get the system administrator to help you.

To stop it from wasting any more of your CPU, run `kill -STOP 11058` (either as `root` or as `www-data`). This signal cannot be intercepted by the program: it simply tells the kernel to not allocate any more CPU time for this process until specifically told otherwise. Effectively, it freezes the process in its tracks.

Then use the `/proc` filesystem to dump the actual program code used by the worm, by using `/proc/<PID of the suspicious process>/exe`. In your case, the PID is 11058, so:

```
 sudo cat /proc/11058/exe >/tmp/dirty_worm
```

This should work even if the worm has deleted its executable file (which it probably has done, to hide itself).

You can then use whatever commands you like to analyze the executable, like

```
strings /tmp/dirty_worm | less
```

to see if it contains any readable text that might help in identifying it and its purpose.

Then, you can inspect all the available information under `/proc` to see what the process was doing. For example, `ls -l /proc/11058/fd` should reveal which files it had open, `ls -l /proc/11058/map_files` should list any libraries and other memory-mapped files it was using, etc.

Once you've gathered all the information you can, you can finally remove this process with `kill -9 11058`. This is one of the few situations where using `kill -9` is definitely justified.

Since it looks like this process got into your server through the web server, you should shut down the web server, check its configuration, remove everything (web applications, CGI/PHP/Perl scripts, etc.) from it that is no longer used, and make sure everything you *do* use is up to date and secure.